# cannot resolve java.util in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, java-8

Using Eclipse 4.5.2 and after import a Java project by others, it is said cannot import java.util? Using Mac OSX. I post the screen snapshot and output of command java, any check list in configurations to see what is wrong? Thanks.

```
/usr/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_102"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.102-b14, mixed mode)
```

[image]

**Edit 1**,

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

your java package library path is not set properly thats why eclipse is not be able to load packages. First set the library path.

Right click on project - >BuildPath - >Configure BuildPath - >Libraries tab - >

Double click on JRE SYSTEM LIBRARY - >Then select alternate JRE

Comment: Thanks Aman, do you mean right click project properties => Java Build Path => Libraries, then click Add Library and select JRE system library? I post my screen snapshot. I tried to find "Configure BuildPath", but cannot find out.

Comment: Right click on project from project Explorer not from menu